# Why does horizontal space after ampersand becomes less?

Tags: spacing, ampersand

Why does the space after the equals sign becomes less if I use the lower code, i.e., if I put ampersand after equals sign?

```
\begin{align*}
A&=B
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
A=&B
\end{align*}
```

Comment: This is a well known alignment problem. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159723/what-does-a-double-ampersand-mean-in-latex . The first answer should be sufficient.

Comment: @pushpen.paul My answer to that question does not cover exactly this issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If a binary relation such as `=` is used in an infix position it gets extra space `[$a=b$]` but of used as a prefix or suffix operator it reverts to mathord spacing compare `[$=a$]` and `[$a=$]`.

The `align` environment is intended to be used as `&=` and adds a `{}` to the start of the second cell so that `&B` is typeset as `{}=B` to ensure that you get the `\mathrel` spacing.

If you need `=&` for a special alignment and want to keep the space use `={}&`

Answer (score 1):

While the question was about the AMS math environments, it's as good a place as any to offer the compare/contrast to the tabbing features of the `tabstackengine` package.  While the package stacks tabbed content, by default, in text mode, an invocation of `\stackMath` will process arguments in math, and then a comparable alignment situation arises as David pointed out for the AMS environments.

The package provides three math padding modes, `\TABbinaryRight` which acts as if a `{}` is added to the end of each cell (this is the package default, which is the opposite of the AMS environment); `\TABbinaryLeft` which acts as if a `{}` is added to the beginning of each cell; and `\TABbinary` which acts as if a `{}` is added to the beginning *and* end of each cell.

The choice will affect the spacing around operators and relations, as shown in the MWE.  So, as a general rule, with `\TABbinaryRight` as the default, one would use `=&` as the `tabstackengine` syntax to produce the "typically" desired result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\TABbinaryRight\tabbedShortstack{A&=B=&C=&-D} (TABbinaryRight -- default)

\TABbinaryLeft\tabbedShortstack{A&=B=&C=&-D} (TABbinaryLeft)

\TABbinary\tabbedShortstack{A&=B=&C=&-D} (TABbinary)
\end{document}
```

[image]