# Trying to align the equations and labelling

Tags: align, labels

I am trying to align the equations, but the alignment has done something wrong to the spacing. The equation in the first line has moved to the right.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=20mm,top=25mm,right=20mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Asymptotic equation of Motion
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}_n (\nabla_{\mu} n_{\nu}) &=& n^{\alpha} \nabla_{\alpha} ( 
\nabla_{\mu} n_{\nu}) + \nabla_{\alpha} n_{\nu} \nabla_{\mu} n^{\alpha} + 
\nabla_{\mu} n_{\alpha} \nabla_{\nu} n^{\alpha} \\
&=& n^{\alpha} \nabla_{\alpha} ( \nabla_{\mu} n_{\nu}) - n^{\alpha} 
\nabla_{\mu} ( \nabla_{\alpha} n_{\nu}) + n^{\alpha} \nabla_{\mu} ( 
\nabla_{\alpha} n_{\nu}) + \nabla_{\alpha} n_{\nu} \nabla_{\mu} n^{\alpha} + 
\nabla_{\mu} n_{\alpha} \nabla_{\nu} n^{\alpha} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

These gives the following result 
[image]

How do I make it appropriate? Also I want to label the second equation as number 1 but not the first line. How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `align` you use `&=`, not `&=&` like in `eqnarray`. For the numbering, change `align*` to `align` and add `\nonumber` to the end of the first line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=20mm,top=25mm,right=20mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Asymptotic equation of Motion
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}_n (\nabla_{\mu} n_{\nu}) &= n^{\alpha} \nabla_{\alpha} ( 
\nabla_{\mu} n_{\nu}) + \nabla_{\alpha} n_{\nu} \nabla_{\mu} n^{\alpha} + 
\nabla_{\mu} n_{\alpha} \nabla_{\nu} n^{\alpha} \nonumber \\ % <----  add \nonumber here
&= n^{\alpha} \nabla_{\alpha} ( \nabla_{\mu} n_{\nu}) - n^{\alpha} 
\nabla_{\mu} ( \nabla_{\alpha} n_{\nu}) + n^{\alpha} \nabla_{\mu} ( 
\nabla_{\alpha} n_{\nu}) + \nabla_{\alpha} n_{\nu} \nabla_{\mu} n^{\alpha} + 
\nabla_{\mu} n_{\alpha} \nabla_{\nu} n^{\alpha} 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The answers in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159723 describe how the columns in `align` work.

Answer (score 5):

For a single equation, the choice should be `split` inside `equation`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=20mm,top=25mm,right=20mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Asymptotic equation of Motion
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathcal{L}_n (\nabla_{\mu} n_{\nu}) 
&= n^{\alpha} \nabla_{\alpha} ( \nabla_{\mu} n_{\nu}) 
   + \nabla_{\alpha} n_{\nu} \nabla_{\mu} n^{\alpha}   
   + \nabla_{\mu} n_{\alpha} \nabla_{\nu} n^{\alpha}
\\
&= n^{\alpha} \nabla_{\alpha} ( \nabla_{\mu} n_{\nu}) 
   - n^{\alpha} \nabla_{\mu} ( \nabla_{\alpha} n_{\nu}) 
   + n^{\alpha} \nabla_{\mu} ( \nabla_{\alpha} n_{\nu}) 
   + \nabla_{\alpha} n_{\nu} \nabla_{\mu} n^{\alpha}  
   + \nabla_{\mu} n_{\alpha} \nabla_{\nu} n^{\alpha}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer the number to be at the bottom, this should be a global decision, that can be accomplished by calling `amsmath` with the `tbtags` option:

```
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}
```

With this single change, the output would become

[image]

Note that `amsmath` alignment environments use `&=` (not `&=&`). I removed the `letterpaper` option, that does nothing and might be a bit unclear.