# Why is the align* environment making such a big space?

Tags: amsmath, environments

The following code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
0           &< t_n - a    &< \delta\\
- \delta    &< a- t_m     &< 0    
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

produces this:

[image]

Could anyone please help me understand why there is such a large horizontal space, and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: because the second ampersand divide columns in `align` environment. Do you  like to align your math expression at two points? In this case you should look for `array` or for `alignat` environments.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159723

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear, what you like to achieve. I guess that you like to align your math expressions at two points. This you can do with use of the `array` or with `alignat` environments:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
0       & < t_n - a & < \delta\\
-\delta & < a - t_m & < 0
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you like to align them only at one point? For example as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
0       & < t_n - a  < \delta\\
-\delta & < a - t_m  < 0
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: in `align` you can have more than one ampersand. However in such cases even ampersands separate columns of math expressions, which are aligned at odd ampersands.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, my intention was to align the math expressions at the two points. So the align environment is used when you have just one aligning point, and the alignat environment is for when you have multiple aligning points?

Comment: @Ovi, your conclusion is correct. With `{...}` after `\begin{alignat}` you inform environment how many columns you like to have. In your particular case, where the middle part of expressions almost have the same length, the difference between (correct) use of `align` and `alignat` is negligible.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer and comment!

Comment: @Ovi, you are welcome!