# Understanding alignment in aligned environment

Tags: align

I am trying to understand how `&` behaves in an aligned environment. So far I have been getting what I need by trial and error.

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  A =& & & B, \\
     & &+&C
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  A =& &B, \\
     &+&C
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I think of `aligned` as a table. So the first equation has 4 columns and 2 rows. For some reason, the second column introduces a lot of spacing (and is left aligned, which is not shown in this example).

In the second example, there are 3 columns on every line. However, again for some reason, the `+` is left-aligned while `B` and `C` are right-aligned.

Can someone explain to me what the rules are? Or point me to a place where I can find them?

Comment: Alignments alternate `rlrlrl...`  After `l` columns, space is autoadded (Can't recall amount).  If you want to avoid space added, you can use `alignat` with slightly altered syntax

Comment: That explains a lot. Thanks! What happens when there are multiple `l` columns? How much space is added? (just read your edit).

Comment: Note that the `tabstackengine` package also has some aligning macros (not environments) that will allow you to customize (or eliminate) the amount of space added after `l` columns.  As I said in earlier comment, `alignat` environments can be used to eliminate space added after `l` columns, for example, `\begin{alignat*}{2}
  A =& &B, \\
     &+&C
\end{alignat*}`

Comment: Actually, in these codes you have only **2** columns with an alignment. More generally, n alignment columns  require  2n–1 ampersands: each column but the first is introduced by an ampersand, and inside that column, the alignment point is marked with another ampersand.

Comment: your align should be `A&=B\\&\quad+C`  (I assume you don't want a comma before +?)

Comment: Have you read the description in the `amsmath` user guide (`texdoc amsldoc`)?  If it isn't clear, please say why, and (if possible) suggest how it can be improved.

Comment: Sort of related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159723/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because explanations are provided in comments.