# Big gap in aligned equations

Tags: spacing, equations, align

I am trying to write some aligned equations, but a get a big gap in the result. Here is my example:

```
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \begin{document}
     \begin{align}
       \mathbf{x}(0)&=\mathbf{x}_0; && \mathbf{v}_x(0) &=\mathbf{v}_{x0}; && \dot{\mathbf{v}}_x(0)&=\omega_c\mathbf{v}_{y0}; \\
       \mathbf{y}(0)&=\mathbf{y}_0; && \mathbf{v}_y(0) &=\mathbf{v}_{y0}; && \dot{\mathbf{v}}_y(0)&=-\omega_c\mathbf{v}_{x0}; \\
       \mathbf{z}(0)&=\mathbf{z}_0; && \mathbf{v}_z(0) &=\mathbf{v}_{z0}; && \dot{\mathbf{v}}_z(0)&=0.
       \label{eq1}
    \end{align}        
\end{document}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

How can I get rid of the space in the second row?

Comment: Where you have `&&`, use just `&`

Comment: By the way, read amsldoc to understand how align environment works and why/when you should use &&, instead of just randomly copy paste code.

Comment: Or read [align - What does a double ampersand (&&) mean in LaTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159723/what-does-a-double-ampersand-mean-in-latex) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `align` environment there are pairs of right and left aligned columns; automatically computed space separates those pairs of columns. To go from a column to the next one you use `&`.

Thus your code should be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}(0)&=\mathbf{x}_0; & \mathbf{v}_x(0) &=\mathbf{v}_{x0}; & \dot{\mathbf{v}}_x(0)&=\omega_c\mathbf{v}_{y0}; \\
\mathbf{y}(0)&=\mathbf{y}_0; & \mathbf{v}_y(0) &=\mathbf{v}_{y0}; & \dot{\mathbf{v}}_y(0)&=-\omega_c\mathbf{v}_{x0}; \\
\mathbf{z}(0)&=\mathbf{z}_0; & \mathbf{v}_z(0) &=\mathbf{v}_{z0}; & \dot{\mathbf{v}}_z(0)&=0.
\label{eq1}
\end{align}        

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you seem to want to label this with just one number, judging from the single label you set, so you probably want `aligned` nested in `equation`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{x}(0)&=\mathbf{x}_0; & \mathbf{v}_x(0) &=\mathbf{v}_{x0}; & \dot{\mathbf{v}}_x(0)&=\omega_c\mathbf{v}_{y0}; \\
\mathbf{y}(0)&=\mathbf{y}_0; & \mathbf{v}_y(0) &=\mathbf{v}_{y0}; & \dot{\mathbf{v}}_y(0)&=-\omega_c\mathbf{v}_{x0}; \\
\mathbf{z}(0)&=\mathbf{z}_0; & \mathbf{v}_z(0) &=\mathbf{v}_{z0}; & \dot{\mathbf{v}}_z(0)&=0.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]