# How to align equation on several characters

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, alignment

Using Latex, I am looking for a way to align equations on several characters. I want to obtain something like that :

`ax  +  bx = c1` 
`a²x  +  bx = c2` 
`a²x  + b²x = c2`

As you can see the idea is that the horizontal alignment occurs at several characters (here the two x appearing at each row, the plus symbol, and the equal symbol), and to generetate such an alignment I want to insert some spaces.
I already tried to use the `align` block but when using several '&', the result shows huge spaces between each '&' positions.

Comment: Have you seen the systeme package? If not, it could be a good idea to look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve your desired output. The code below shows 2 possible solutions. After i struggled a lot with it myself someone recommended me the `array` environment. Also an interesting article for this topic might be [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159723/what-does-a-double-ampersand-mean-in-latex).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \begin{aligned}
            ax &+ bx &= c_1 \\
            a^2x &+ bx &= c_2 \\
            a^2x &+ b^2x &= c_3
        \end{aligned}
    \end{align*}
    
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{array}{ccccc}
            ax &+& bx &=& c_1 \\
            a^2x &+& bx &=& c_2 \\
            a^2x &+& b^2x &=& c_3
        \end{array}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

The code above generates this
[image: aligned_example]

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{alignat}{2}
     ax & + bx & & = c1 \\
    a²x & + bx & & = c2 \\
    a²x & + b²x & & = c2
    \end{alignat}

    \end{document}
```

[image]